why can't I enter the virtual environment venv?
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\tgbot> python -m venv .venv
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\tgbot\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\tgbot> .venv\Scripts\activate
.venv\Scripts\activate : The module '.venv' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module .venv'.
At line:1 char:1
+ .venv\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.venv\Scripts\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule

created a .venv virtual environment, when trying to enter it, the following error appears

Try to create a new virtual environment using interface commands.       https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command
